# Voice assistant for raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I am making an assistant bot in which a user input its queries using touchscreen keyboard and than after processing i wants to deliver the result through audio output can anyone suggest any APIs for this.

Comment: I would recommend google

Comment: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-google-assistant/